# Handling multiple containers over one pipe in CICS web service call from COBOL

Tags: soap, cobol, cics

We are trying to integrate a COBOL program with a SOAP service using CICS 4.1.  One challenge is that the response contains a variable number of return codes, and this complicates the copybook.

1. The `DFHWS2LS` program generates two 01 levels in the copybook for the response structure (see copybook snippet below). Should this second 01 level be used in linkage, or should it be considered a working-storage field?
2. When dealing with a single single container going over a pipe there are a number of activities that the CICS program needs to do (see example below). When we have two containers does this all have to be done twice?

I've searched the Internet and IBM documentation, but haven't found an example of how to handle this. It seems to occur any time there is a variable number of elements in the WSDL schema. A COBOL example of how someone handled two containers going over the same pipe would be most helpful.

Here is the copybook snippet (the initial 01 level is supplied in the program):

```
05  ObligationResponse.                                   
    10  ReturnCodes-num            PIC S9(9) COMP-5 SYNC. 
    10  ReturnCodes-cont           PIC X(16).             

(other response structure elements deleted for brevity)

01  pfcsO01-ReturnCodes.                                   
    05  DiscrepancyCode                PIC S9(9) COMP-5 SYNC.
    05  DiscrepancyLevelCode           PIC S9(9) COMP-5 SYNC.
```

Here the code we are using to set up the first container, and we're stumped as to how to incorporate a second container.

```
PERFORM 2000-PUT-INPUT-INTO-CONTAINER
    THRU 2000-EXIT.                   
PERFORM 6000-CHECK-CONTAINER-COMMAND 
    THRU 6000-EXIT.                   
PERFORM 3000-INVOKE-WEBSERVICES      
    THRU 3000-EXIT.                   
PERFORM 4000-CHECK-WEBSERVICE-COMMAND
    THRU 4000-EXIT.                   
PERFORM 5000-RECEIVE-RESPONSE        
    THRU 5000-EXIT.                   
PERFORM 6000-CHECK-CONTAINER-COMMAND 
    THRU 6000-EXIT.                   
PERFORM 7000-USER-CODE-TO-FMT-OUTPUT 
    THRU 7000-EXIT.                   
PERFORM 9000-TERMINATE-CICS          
    THRU 9000-EXIT.                   
GOBACK.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ReturnCodes-num` tells you how many instances of `pfcsO01-ReturnCodes` are present in the container named in `ReturnCodes-cont`.

`pfcsO01-ReturnCodes` maps to one instance.  One way to deal with this is to place `pfcsO01-ReturnCodes` in your Linkage Section, use either `CEEGTST` or `EXEC CICS GETMAIN` to obtain storage of size `LENGTH OF pfcsO01-ReturnCodes * ReturnCodes-num`, and `SET ADDRESS OF pfcsO01-ReturnCodes` to that of your newly obtained storage.

If you like to live dangerously, you can add the length of `pfcsO01-ReturnCodes` to the address obtained to move through the instances as you repeatedly `SET ADDRESS OF pfcsO01-ReturnCodes` to that of the incremented pointer.  Or, if you prefer to live safely, you can declare a variably-occurring array of `pfcsO01-ReturnCodes` (with `Occurs Depending On`) and set the object of the ODO to `ReturnCodes-num`.